# How to execute behind code from embedded asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, iframe

I have this task I’m working on and that is getting rid of the old iframes on my website. Let’s use page1.aspx and page2.aspx for examples.
Currently, page2.aspx sits in an iframe that is embedded into page1.aspx and loads a form for the customer to fill out. In the .cs code of page2.aspx, it does some validation and calls to the DB to store the customer information.

Now I am not sure where to go from here. I basically took the URL that was being loaded into the iframe and used the JQuery .load() function to load the URL into a page1.aspx DIV.
The form loads but once I try and submit, an exception is thrown and it crashes my webpage.

My question is how would I go about executing the behind code from page2.aspx within the .load() div in page1.aspx?

I was thinking about writing some web methods that use AJAX to call the functions and do it that way. I’m not even sure if the 2 aspx pages can communicate with each other because I used the .load() function to render page2.aspx

Does anyone have any input on how to go about this? If I am going about it the wrong way, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered changing page2.aspx into an UserControl (ascx)?

Comment: Do you think that would be a better approach? I have looked into it and was trying to make a control but wanted to try AJAX first. I dont think I can access the back code from just loading a url with the .load() function. I think it just renders html. The UC might be the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if is the best approach, but it certainly lets you access the code behind between the UC and the Page.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will most likely end up trying this out. I just want to get rid of the iframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a usercontrol of Page2
And Use Usercontrol insted of Iframe in Page1